# Site icons are too big when choosing a parent user

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, parent-user

When choosing a site for chat parent user, the icons of all sites except "The Stack Exchange Network" are too big and look awkward:

> [image]

Can they all be resized to the smaller version, as the "The Stack Exchange Network" already is?

Browser: Chrome latest version, both under Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: [Looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeIQ9.png) to me.

Comment: @Pandya weird. What browser? Added my own, maybe it's browser specific. Also, where exactly you change it from? I do it from [my chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/29968/shadow-wizard), your screenshot appear different.

Comment: [Abrowser](https://trisquel.info/en/wiki/abrowser-help) (fork of firefox); -- [for your profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCcjh.jpg).

Comment: @Pandya oh, it's different since you're a moderator (so you can change the parent site of any other user). Check with your own chat user and see what you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed now. That code was still making the assumption that a favicon is always 16x16 pixels large, and that's not really a realistic assumption in 2017.

Comment: Are you on chat (project) again? *crossing fingers* :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm doing a bit of design bug duty today. Chat happens to have a few design bugs ;p